# Getting echofunc.vim to work

Tags: vim

I came across [echofunc.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1735) today (from a link in SO). Since I'm rubbish at remembering the order of function parameters, it looked like a very useful tool for me.

But the documentation is a bit lean on installation! And I've not been able to find any supplementary resources on the internet.

I'm trying to get it running on a RHEL box. I've copied the script into ~/.vim/plugin/echofunc.vim however no prompt when I type in a function name followed by '('. I've tried adding

```
let g:EchoFuncLangsUsed = ["php","java","cpp"]
```

to my .vimrc - still no prompting.

I'm guessing it needs to read from a dictionary somewhere - although there is a file in /usr/share/vim/vim70/ftplugin/php.vim, this is the RH default and does not include an explicit function list.

I'm not too bothered about getting hints on the functions/methods I've defined - just trying to get hints for the built-in functions. I can see there is a dictionary file [available here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=534) which appears to provide the resources required for echofunc.vim, I can't see how I set this up.

TIA,

Comment: BTW: set dictionary+=/home/symcbean/PHP.dict did not help

Answer (score 1):

It expects a `tags` file, the last line of the description describes exactly how to generate it:

```
ctags -R --fields=+lS .
```

It works here with PHP but not with JS. Your mileage may vary.

I didn't know about this plugin, thanks for the info.

You should try [phpcomplete.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3171), it shows a prototype of the current function in a scratchpad. It is PHP only, though.

Comment: That will generate ctags for my files - not for the PHP builtin funcions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea how to create such a `tags` file. PHP's source not being written in PHP, using `ctags` on it won't be very useful.

Comment: Hoho look what I've found: [a reasonably recent PHP `tags` file](http://code.google.com/p/php-tags-file/).